# A loop that works before but not after

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a problem that is strange. I have the same code for three buttons but it works for the first and not for the others. How is it possible? Is there someone who can explain it to me? Thanks so much. 
I can click the buttons (B and C) ones and not twice. What's going on? In the first case (button A) it works but then it just show one card and not two.

```
@SuppressLint("Recycle")  
public class GameActivity extends Activity {  
protected View buttonA;  
protected View buttonB;  
protected View buttonC;  
protected View buttonD;  
final int randomInt1 = 0;  
final int randomInt2 = 0;  
int a = 0;  
int b = 0;  
int c = 0;  
int d = 0;  
int e = 0;  


@Override  

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);  
    findViewById(R.id.A);  
    Resources res = getResources();  
    String[] StringDeck = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.StringDeck);  
    int[] DeckDraw = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.DeckDraw);  

    final HashMap<String, Integer> DECK = new HashMap<String, Integer>();  
    for(int i = 0; i < DeckDraw.length; i++){  
        DECK.put(StringDeck[i], DeckDraw[i]);  
    }  
    final TypedArray Deck = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.DeckDraw);  
    final ViewGroup groupButtons1 = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);  

View v1;  

final Button backgroundA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.A);  
final Button backgroundB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B);  
final Button backgroundC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.C);  
final Button backgroundD = (Button) findViewById(R.id.D);  
final Button backgroundE = (Button) findViewById(R.id.E);  

final Random random1 = new Random();  
final Random random2 = new Random();  

for(int i = 0; i < groupButtons1.getChildCount(); i++) {  
    v1 = groupButtons1.getChildAt(i);  
    if(v1 instanceof Button) v1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {  


        @SuppressLint("CutPasteId") //Legato ai button inferiori  
        public void onClick(View view){  
        backgroundA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){  
            public void onClick(View view){  
                if(a < 2){  
                int randomInt1 = random1.nextInt(Deck.length());  
                int drawableIDA = Deck.getResourceId(randomInt1, -1);  
                backgroundA.setBackgroundResource(drawableIDA);  
                a ++;  
            }  
            }  
        });  



    backgroundB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){  

        public void onClick(View view){  
            if (b < 2){    
                int randomInt2 = random1.nextInt(Deck.length());  
                int drawableIDB = Deck.getResourceId(randomInt2, -1);  
                backgroundB.setBackgroundResource(drawableIDB);  
                b ++;  
            }  
            backgroundB.setEnabled(false);  

        }             
        });  

            backgroundC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){  

                public void onClick(View view){  
                    if (c < 2){    
                        int randomInt3 = random1.nextInt(Deck.length());  
                        int drawableIDC = Deck.getResourceId(randomInt3, -1);  
                        backgroundC.setBackgroundResource(drawableIDC);  
                        c ++;  
                    }  
                    backgroundC.setEnabled(false);    

                }  
                });
```

Sorry for the indentation

Comment: Do you ever reset `a` when you need it reset?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: You never reset the variables a,b,c to 0 again, so if you press them, they just skip the loop.

Comment: Yeah but I should press them twice before loop stopping

Comment: You appear to be disabling buttons B and C with `setEnabled(false)` when you click on them, but not button A.  Could that explain why they behave differently?

Comment: `Sorry for the indentation` fixing it would be more useful

Comment: Ok.... I need someone that slap me on the face. Thanks jab

Answer (score 0):

Your program is storing the values of `a`,`b`,`c` but the only change that will ever be made to them is to have them incremented. After a few clicks, `a`,`b`,`c` will be above 2 and will never be able to go down below 2.

Comment: Yeah, I don't need that they go under 2. I just need the case a = 0, a = 1. Then stop. I don't have to call them again